# path to css stylesheet seems to be correct, but doesn't work in preview page

Tags: html, css

These are my folders: [index.ejs is inside Markdown Blog/views/articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1D7u.png)

This is the path to my css stylesheet: [../../css/styles.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOFPc.png)

When I ctrl+click the path, it does go to my css file, but when I preview the website the css in there is clearly not working. I've tried changing the path to ././css/styles.css, ../../css/styles.css, tried changing the file to another folder along with the path too but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers deal in URLs, not in file paths.

The server-side file path between the view template and the CSS file is irrelevant.

What matters is the URL to the route which renders the view and the URL to the route which serves the static CSS file.

Comment: I uploaded my css file online and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>

XXXXXX

</body>
</html>
```

you need to attach your Css file in HTML index page

Comment: I did that, it's in the second image. I apologize for not being clear as to where that line of code was.